# Get route by name - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

I want dynamic uri for Auth routes depending on the language.
Is there a way to get a route result by name?

For example with the Auth routes:

```
Route::get(route('login'));
```

Thank you for your ideas...

Comment: why are creating a route of a route ?

Comment: I want dynamic uri for Auth routes... depends on language.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use them as such:

```
//Routes
Route::post('/login',[
  'uses'=>'HomeController@login',
  'as'=>'login'
]);

// Calling them in blade
{{route('login')}}   -> xxxxx/login
```

You can still get more information on the best documentation of the world: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url for the named route, for example to use it in your views, you should just use `route('routename')` (ofcourse you should replace `route_name` with the name of your route). You do not need the `Route::get` around that, the Route::get/post/put/patch/delete functions are for defining new routes, not to get the url for a route.

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes on how to create named routes and properly link to them.